# Gnuplot and unstructured data is it possible

Tags: gnuplot

So far, I have been able to generate 2D contour plots using `pm3d` for a 2D structured data. However, I have got some data files that contains some flow `visualisation` of an unstructured grid that I am trying to plot next to the structured data. So far, I have found some links pointing to some scripts on how to generate contour plots [Link](https://grantingram.wordpress.com/plotting-2d-unstructured-data-using-free-software/), but it seems that the only way to do it is through `dgrid3d`, which only generates contours lines rather than the surface flow like this picture [image].

I am just wondering if there is a better way to generate similar plot using `gnuplot tool`.

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct that dgrid3d only produces lines.  It is a preprocessing step for your data, which can subsequent be plotted using any style you want.

Here is an example using a pre-generated set of random points with Gaussian distribution.  The code shown should work with gnuplot version 5.2 or newer. A slightly simpler plot command is possible in the current gnuplot version but the one shown still works also.

```
set view map
unset key
set cbtics format ""  # no tic labels on the colorbar
set palette cubehelix negative

#
# Generate a grid from point density of previously-generated Gaussian
#
set dgrid3d 50,50 gauss kdensity

#
# Make all contour lines black
#
set contour base
set cntrparam levels incremental 0,200
set cntrparam firstlinetype 101
set for [L=101:110] linetype L linecolor "black" dashtype solid
set style textbox opaque noborder

set pm3d explicit at b

#
# Order of drawing is important.
# First the surface, then the lines, then the labels
#
splot $random using 1:2:(1) with pm3d, \
      '' using 1:2:(1) with lines nosurface, \
      '' using 1:2:(1):("") with labels boxed
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ethan, thank you very much for the help! testing your script above, it doesn't seem to like set cntrparm firstlinetype 101.

Comment: What version of gnuplot are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.4~

Comment: Weird.  I tested all versions back to 5.2.6 before posting.  The figure I attached was generated with 5.4.0.   Well, you can comment out those lines but then it will draw the contours in the default color sequence.

Comment: You say your results are "similar to your plot above", which in turn seems similar to the example plot you provided.   Please show your current plot and describe what is wrong or unexpected or missing or different from what you want. Since I don't know what you are aiming for, just sending the data won't help.

Comment: I think I got it to work on my data as well! Thanks for the help! Your answer clarified and resolved my confusion.

Comment: Do you have to have an example for 4D plot with contours e.g. x,y,z and velocity for instance?

Comment: Start a new question for 4D contours